# Stemming and lemming words

Tags: python, nlp, stemming, lemmatization

I have a text document i need to use stemming and Lemmatization on. I have already cleaned the data and tokenised it as well as removing stop words

what i need to do is take the list as an input and return a dict and the dict should have the keys 'original stem and lemmma. and the values being the nth word transformed in that way

```
  snowball stemmer is defined as Stemmer()
  and WordNetLemmatizer is defined as lemmatizer()
```

heres the code ive written but it does give our an error

```
def find_roots(token_list, n):
n = 2
original = tokens
stem = [ele for sub in original for idx, ele in 
enumerate(sub.split()) if idx == (n - 1)]
stem = stemmer(stem)
lemma = [ele for sub in original for idx, ele in 
enumerate(sub.split()) if idx == (n - 1)]
lemma = lemmatizer()
return
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: please edit post to correct indentation

Comment: Please post the tracelog, properly format the code, read [ask] and [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really don't understand what you are trying to do in the list comprehensions, so I'll just write how I would do it:

```
from nltk import WordNetLemmatizer, SnowballStemmer

lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
stemmer = SnowballStemmer("english")


def find_roots(token_list, n):
    token = token_list[n]
    stem = stemmer.stem(token)
    lemma = lemmatizer.lemmatize(token)
    return {"original": token, "stem": stem, "lemma": lemma}


roots_dict = find_roots(["said", "talked", "walked"], n=2)
print(roots_dict)
> {'original': 'walked', 'stem': 'walk', 'lemma': 'walked'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want with `spacy` like below: *(In many cases `spacy` performs better than `nltk`.)*

```
# $ pip install -U spacy

import spacy
from nltk import WordNetLemmatizer, SnowballStemmer

sp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
stemmer = SnowballStemmer("english")


words = ['compute', 'computer', 'computed', 'computing', 'said', 'talked', 'walked']
for word in words:
    print(f'Orginal Word : {word}')
    print(f'Stemmer with nltk : {stemmer.stem(word)}')
    print(f'Lemmatization with nltk : {lemmatizer.lemmatize(word)}')
    
    sp_word = sp(word)
    print(f'Lemmatization with spacy : {sp_word[0].lemma_}')
```

Output:

```
Orginal Word : compute
Stemmer with nltk : comput
Lemmatization with nltk : compute
Lemmatization with spacy : compute
Orginal Word : computer
Stemmer with nltk : comput
Lemmatization with nltk : computer
Lemmatization with spacy : computer
Orginal Word : computed
Stemmer with nltk : comput
Lemmatization with nltk : computed
Lemmatization with spacy : compute
Orginal Word : computing
Stemmer with nltk : comput
Lemmatization with nltk : computing
Lemmatization with spacy : compute
Orginal Word : said
Stemmer with nltk : said
Lemmatization with nltk : said
Lemmatization with spacy : say
Orginal Word : talked
Stemmer with nltk : talk
Lemmatization with nltk : talked
Lemmatization with spacy : talk
Orginal Word : walked
Stemmer with nltk : walk
Lemmatization with nltk : walked
Lemmatization with spacy : walk
```